# What is Spirituality? What is a Spiritual path?

Tags: gods, moksha, spirituality

What is the spiritual path that people go through... Is it for moksha? And why does it have so many restrictions like.. no sense enjoyment, no desires etc...

Comment: Spirituality does not have restrictions.  Desires are not wrong but we should be pure before we get anything what we want. But when we're not pure, and not ready to purify,  we try to attain it in crooked way. That will lead to destruction.

Comment: Second spirituality is not something different as it is seen now. Entire life we live is spiritual but we don't realise it. Spirituality is living a life without any ego of I.

Comment: You can have desires want to enjoy but before that purify your inner self from impurities. Pure mind will satisfy all our desires. Second these desires doesn't have ending because as senses come in contact with different objects it will seem better than previous ones... so this will have no end. Consequently you will be in cycle of birth/death. The day you surpass ordinary nature of mind, you will be freed from death.

Comment: One who has realisation of God his wants will definitely be satisfied!

Comment: What are the impurities that one needs to purify?

Answer (score 2):

Our scriptures had observed :

> आहारनिद्राभयमैथुनञ्च एतत् सामान्यं पशुभिर्नराणाम्। धर्मो हि एको ह्यधिको विशेषो धर्मेण हीनाः पशुभिः समानाः॥ meaning that taking food, sleep, fear and sex are common among men and animals. The only difference is Righoutness or Spirituality.

So Spirituality is what makes a man different from an animal.

What is the essence of Spirituality? The smallest list our scriptures give is :

> अहिंसा सत्यमस्तेयं शौचः संयममेव च meaning **non-violence, Truthfulness, Non-stealing, Purity and Control of the senses are what make men different from the animals.**

Upto this, there is no mention of God even!

Most of us need God to come out of fear and manifest the features of Spirituality in life with absolute perfection.

God says in the Gita (Chapter 7, sloka 16):

> Four classes of people of virtuous deeds adore Me: the afflicted, the seeker of Knowledge, the seeker of wealth[any material gain] and the man of Knowledge.(Translation by Swami Gambhirananda)

So He Himself makes it clear who worships Him and why.

I think the above answers your queries.

(Reference: Jnaniguru by Nigamananda Paramahamsa, Halisahar Saraswata Math)